# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]

Tags: c#

I'm getting the following error and I'm having some difficulty on how I can write the following snippet of code bellow to prevent the following error before casting, I tried the following solution and no luck...

Error: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]**

```
byte[] pictureAsByteArray = (byte[])reader.GetValue(ordinals.GetOrdinal("xxxSignature"));
```

Solution Doesn't work:

```
if ((reader.GetValue(ordinals.GetOrdinal("xxxSignature")!= null))
else() then casting
```

Comment: FYI `DBNull` is not the same thing as `null`...

Comment: `if ((reader.GetValue(ordinals.GetOrdinal("xxxSignature")!= DBNull.Value))`

Comment: What is the definition of `ordinals`

Comment: the ordinals is a Dictionary<String,int>.

Comment: Then check in ordinals if the key "xxxSignature" exists, and only if it exists should you go into `byte[] pictureAsByteArray = (byte[])reader.GetValue(ordinals.GetOrdinal("xxxSignature"));`